# Is this a functional and reliable Reverse polarity protection?

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, ups, reverse-polarity, production

[image]

Guys, I am trying here to design a UPS controlling board, I designed this circuit and it was to some extent functional and it draws approximately 16mA - 20mA (I don't want to use the traditional one MOSFET circuit because I need to charge the batteries too, so this circuit would be MCU controlled too so I can charge the battery easily), however I don't know how safe and reliable is the design(the load will draw approximately 60A(I will use a higher current rated MOSFET). What do you think? Feel free to suggest any ideas to make it better

Comment: This provides absolutely no reverse polarity protection, the body diode will conduct if the 12 V supply is reversed.

Comment: you mean the MOSFET?
if so, then the MOSFET is not the problem because the batteries would be connected at the + and - Op amp pins

Comment: I see, so the 12 V rail doesn't need reverse polarity protection, you're just trying to prevent turn-on of the load if the battery is installed backwards.  In that case it looks like you might be OK.

Comment: Wish I could send you a video for it, it is functioning correctly, but would it be reliable if used as a product(inside the UPS controlling board)?

Comment: I'd use a true comparator rather than an op-amp, then use a resistor from the output to the positive input to provide hysteresis.

Comment: I tried to use lm393 but unfortunately it didn't work with me(I used the same schematic above) so if you have a modified drawing that would help me a lot

Comment: Connecting the output directly to the + input isn't the way to go.  If you want hysteresis use a high-value resistor between the output and the + input.

Comment: For me it would be better to remove hysteresis to provide under voltage protection(or you mean the opposite that providing hysteresis would provide under voltage protection?)

Comment: A little hysteresis is a good thing so you don't get "chatter" when you're right on the edge of the under-voltage threshold.  But you can add it or not as you see fit.

Comment: I understand you, for that I will be adding a feedback resistor between 20k-100k, actually I am trying to make an under voltage protection too but it doesn't fit with this design